# Error when Using YouTube Data API and Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, alamofire, youtube-data-api

I'm using the YouTube Data API and Alamofire to display my YouTube channel's videos and they update dynamicly. Here's my code:

```
func getFeedVideo() {        

Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists", parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

        if let JSON = response.result.value {

            if let dictionary = JSON as? [String: Any] {

                var arrayOfVideos = [Video]()

                for video in dictionary["items"] as! NSArray {
                    //  Create video objects off of the JSON response
                    let videoObj = Video()
                    videoObj.videoID = (video as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "snippet.resourceId.videoId") as! String
                    videoObj.videoTitle = (video as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "snippet.title") as! String
                    videoObj.videoDescription = (video as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "snippet.description") as! String
                    videoObj.videoThumbnailUrl = (video as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url") as! String

                    arrayOfVideos.append(videoObj)

                }
                self.videoArray = arrayOfVideos
                if self.delegate != nil {
                    self.delegate!.dataReady()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

on the line `for video in dictionary["items"] as! NSArray {`. In the console, I see

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

The data is being displayed in a `UITableView`. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use force type cast. It may cause your app crash. Always use if let or guard let. Try to iterate it like that

```
if let dictionary = JSON as? [String: Any] {
var arrayOfVideos = [Video]()
if let playlist = dictionary["items"] as? [Any] {

    for i in 0..<playlist.count {

        let videoObj = Video()
        if let video = playlist[i] as? [String: Any] {
            if let videoId = video["id"] as? String {
                videoObj.videoID = videoId
            }

            if let snippet = video["snippet"] as? [String: Any] {
                if let videoTitle = snippet["title"] as? String {
                    videoObj.videoTitle = videoTitle
                }

                if let videoDescription = snippet["description"] as? String {
                    videoObj.videoDescription = videoDescription
                }
            }

            if let thumbnails = video["thumbnails"] as? [String: Any]{
                if let maxres = thumbnails["maxres"] as? [String: Any] {
                    if let url = maxres["url"] as? String {
                        videoObj.videoThumbnailUrl = url
                    }
                }
            }
            arrayOfVideos.append(videoObj)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm getting an error `Type Int has no subscript members` on lines `if let videoId = video["id"] as? String {`, `if let snippet = video["snippet"] as? [String: Any] {`, and `if let thumbnails = video["thumbnails"] as? [String: Any]{`

Answer (score 0):

This means that you do not have a value for items in your dictionary, or you are accessing it improperly.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to make a force cast to NSArray. This will crash you app if `dictionary["items"]` is not a NSArray.
I recommend you to put a break point before the loop to check the type of your `dictionary["items"]`.

**Example:**

```
guard let items = dictionary["items"] as? NSArray else { return }
```